# Using github with Aptana standalone

Tags: git, github, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Standalone and am trying to setup Github, but when I go under preference, team, git and browse to the path of the git application file, it gives me an error message that "Value must be an existing file". Any suggestions?

Edit: I am actually using the software on a Mac.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer for Mac instead of Windows, but the same idea applies.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that you do have a git in your path

```
which git
/path/to/git
```

(Either by installing a [git on Mac](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac) or a [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/), if you are on windows)

Then, and only then you can reference the `git`.

If it still doesn't work, check the Aptana logs (`Help > Aptana > View Log file`)

Comment: I installed Github for Mac, is the git executable supposed to be GitHub.app?

Comment: @Anonymous it can (or it can be an executable from another git installation). In any case, the question is: is git part of your `$PATH`? (have the `which git`). If it is not, it won't work.

Comment: Can you explain that further? When I type which git into terminal, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @Anonymous that means git isn't in your `PATH`, hence your issue. Modify your `PATH` in order to reference the directory which includes `git`.

Comment: I have installed github for Mac, how should I proceed? What should /path/to/git lead to? The .app? Sorry I am a little confused.

Comment: @Anonymous find the directory which contains the git executable included in your GitHub for Mac installation, and add that directory to your `$PATH` (http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/, or http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.UZMZj6KBlp8)

Comment: Added it to $PATH, but still no luck.

Comment: @Anonymous did you re-launch the Eclipse, from the shell session where you modified the `$PATH`? Or did you reboot, check that the `PATH` was still modified, and then relaunched Eclipse?